# Why isn't the user I clicked deleted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't delete the one which I select on the page. It deletes every time the first one on the list.

I don't know if it has anything to do with the backend. If that's the case you have to tell me, then I would take it in with me in the backend.

My UserManagement.js:

```
function UserManagement({ history }) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
  const { loading  } = userLogin;
  const { users} = userList;

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  },[dispatch, history]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      dispatch(deleteUserAction(id));
    }
  };

  
  console.log(userList);
  console.log(users);
  return (
    <MainScreen title={`List of Users`}>
       <Link to="/createUser" id="OpenCreateUserDialogButton">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          Create new User
        </Button>
      </Link>
      
      {loading && <Loading />}
     
      {users &&
        users?.map((users) => (
         
          <Accordion>
            <Card style={{ margin: 10 }} key={users._id}>
              <Card.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <span
                  // onClick={() => ModelShow(note)}
                  style={{
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    flex: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }}
                >
                      
                      {users.userID}               
                </span>
                <div>
                  <Link to="/profileedit">
                    <Button
                    id="EditButton"
                    >Edit</Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button
                      id="DeleteButton"
                      variant="danger"
                      className="mx-2"
                      onClick={() => deleteHandler(users.id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </div>
              </Card.Header>
```

And this is my userAction:

```
  export const deleteUserAction = (_id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_REQUEST,
      });
  
      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = getState();
  
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/";
  
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token.token}`,
        },
      };
      console.log(userInfo.token.token);
      const { data } = await axios.delete(url, config);
  
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_FAIL,
        payload: message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Backend (Server):

```
exports.deleteUser = async (request, response) => {
  try{
      await User.deleteOne({id: request.params.id});
      response.status(201).json("User deleted Successfully");
  } catch (error){
      response.status(409).json({ message: error.message});     
  }
}
```

Comment: "Are you sure? you want to delete" - your question mark is in the wrong place, it should be at the end of the sentence.

Comment: You are not passing the `id` of the user to the `axios.delete`. Can you post your backend code?

Comment: @LucaPizzini I edit it now to my Code you can look after it

Comment: @Phobos What do you mean with end of the sentennce ? it´s the if condition question..

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending an `axios.delete()` call request. But you're not passing any identifier of the exact user you want to actually delete to that API request.

You need to pass an identifier as a parameter with the URL you pass in `axios.delete()`.

Example:

```js
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/$_id";

      ...

      const { data } = await axios.delete(url, config);
  
      ...
```

Comment: I have tried it .. id use now http://localhost:8080/user/:id but it doesn´t change anything

Comment: On your backend, if you try to `console.log(request.params.id)`, does it print the id? If not, please include the function code of `User.deleteOne()` in your question.

Comment: If I delete some one pushing on Postman http://localhost:8080/user/{the id of the user} then it´s delete

Comment: You haven't answered my question. When you send the request from Postman it's most expected that `console.log(request.params.id)` prints the id. But does that print when you use your React App to send that request?